# RStudio Server - How to reset the password?

Tags: rstudio, rstudio-server

I have RStudio server installed in my system (local).  I forgot my username/password to login to the server. How to reset them? (I use Ubuntu 14.10)

Answer (score 1):

I guess that RStudio uses the system username/password.
Well, it worked for me.
I won't forget it again. :)

Comment: Please, Add the steps for any new person that comes along.

Comment: It queries /etc/passwd and you need a 'local' user. LDAP, AD won't work.